# Convert a Range of more than row to a usable array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I have VBA code in Excel to convert a Range of multiple rows and columns to an Array so that I can convert it to string and store the information as a string:

```vb
Sub pruebaString()
    Dim str As String
    Dim ar As Variant
    
    ar = Hoja2.Names("AREA1").RefersToRange
    Debug.Print TypeName(ar(1)) 'GIVES ERROR
    str = Join(ar(1)) 'GIVES ERROR
    Debug.print ar(1,2) 'outputs the results correctly.
    debug.print LBound(ar) & ", " & UBound(ar) 'outputs the expected bounds.
End Sub
```

Gives me an 'out of bounds' error. The Range is an area of 4x4 so the array should be a bidimensional array.

Trying to do a Join of ar(1) also gives 'out of bounds error'.

The code to convert it to an array, I took it from the internet. Apparently it is the only thing it takes to do the job, by assigning a range to a Variant non array variable.

It seems to have the structure of a bi-dimensional array and accessing it like ar(1,1), ar(1,2) and so on works but when trying to join each of the inner arrays doesn't.

I want to join the inner arrays and then join everything together with a different delimiter, so that I have a string of rows and columns like 1,2,1;4,2,1 and so on.

I'm using Excel 2002

Comment: For a 2D array, you need two arguments (row and column) to access an element, e.g. `arr(0, 1)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, but shouldn't i be able to get the first array like ar(1)? a bidimensional array is an array of arrays, or that's what I understand, So I should be able to pick every inner array individually.

Comment: No, a two-dimensional array is not an [array of arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: ... although it could be, surely :)

Comment: The code you showed here is half-nonsence, as far as Excel VBA is concerned. What is the actual problem/task you are facing? BTW, Range object in Excel is an array, structurally. The code looks like an awkward and unsuccessful adaptation of some other (popular) scripting language's code... Excel version is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

### Join Array Row or Column

- An easy way to get a row or a column as a 1D array is by using `Application.Index` with `Application.Transpose` with its limitations (slow, the number of elements is limited).
- Using the row or the column of the range with `Application.Transpose` may be more efficient.
- The most efficient way would be to write a function that will loop through the rows or columns of the 2D array and return a 1D array.
- To test this, copy the code to a standard module of a new workbook and put a table of values starting in cell `A1` of `Sheet1`. In the VBE Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) monitor the output.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub JoinArrayRowOrColumn()
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value ' 2D one-based array
    
    ' Join first row (note the 'double transpose').
    Dim rArr As Variant: rArr = Application.Transpose( _
        Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Data, 1, 0)))
    Debug.Print Join(rArr, ", ")
    
    ' Join first column.
    Dim cArr As Variant
    cArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Data, 0, 1))
    Debug.Print Join(cArr, ", ")

    ' Without using the 'indermediate' ('Data') array (probably more efficient):
    
    rArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rg.Rows(1).Value))
    Debug.Print Join(rArr, ", ")
    
    cArr = Application.Transpose(rg.Columns(1).Value)
    Debug.Print Join(cArr, ", ")

End Sub
```

**The Function for a Row**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a row of a 2D array in a 1D array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrRow( _
    ByVal Data As Variant, _
    ByVal RowIndex As Long, _
    Optional ByVal FirstIndex As Long = 0) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "ArrRow"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Function
    If RowIndex < LBound(Data, 1) Then Exit Function
    If RowIndex > UBound(Data, 1) Then Exit Function
    
    Dim LB2 As Long: LB2 = LBound(Data, 2)
    Dim UB2 As Long: UB2 = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim cDiff As Long: cDiff = LB2 - FirstIndex

    Dim rArr As Variant: ReDim rArr(FirstIndex To FirstIndex + UB2 - LB2)

    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = LB2 To UB2
        rArr(c - cDiff) = Data(RowIndex, c)
    Next c
    
    ArrRow = rArr
'    Debug.Print ProcName & ": [LB=" & LBound(ArrRow) _
'        & ",UB=" & UBound(ArrRow) & "]"
'    Debug.Print ProcName & ": [" & Join(ArrRow, ", ") & "]"
   
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Sub ArrRowTEST()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Note that if rg contains more than one (contiguous) cell,
    ' rg.Value is actually a 2D one-based array already.
    Dim rArr As Variant: rArr = ArrRow(rg.Value, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(rArr) Then
        Debug.Print Join(rArr, ", ")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks easier to read and shorter to write a function to loop through the range and create the string.
I did it that way finally. I wanted VBA to have an even shorter method as the one I was trying. The one with the transpose which you wrote looks more confusing and larger.

Comment: Shorter code is NOT a better code, more often than not!